# Is there a way to inline this javascript code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React framework.

Here is what I have:

```
const myObject = this.props.objects.find(({id}) => ({id} === this.state.selectedObject.id));
const name = !isEmpty(myObject) ? myObject.name : '';
```

I avoid doing the following:

```
const name = !isEmpty(this.props.objects.find(({id}) => ({id} === this.state.selectedObject.id))) ? this.props.objects.find(({id}) => ({id} === this.state.selectedObject.id)).name : '';
```

because it doesn't make sense to execute find() twice. But I'm just wondering if there's some nice syntax that can make this a one-liner that I'm missing.

Comment: really `{id} === this.state.selectedObject.id`? its never true.

Comment: I mean... you could pass the `find` result as an argument to an IIFE, but that's arguably even less readable that your second formulation: `const name = (o=>!isEmpty(o)?o.name:'')(this.props.objects.find(...))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a combination of [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) and default parameter like:

```
const {name = ''} = this.props.objects.find(({id}) => id === this.state.selectedObject.id) || {};
```

In case `find()` method, does not find anything then `undefined` is returned and that will set `name` to an empty string.

Comment: You can't destructure `undefined`, so you'd have to add a `|| {}` at the end.

Comment: I like this answer, but Nina's solution imo is slightly easier to read. Any advantage here vs the answer below? Or a matter of preference?

Comment: congrats, your answer wins :) there seems to be a bug in babel or webpack that prevents me from using optional operator

Answer (score 3):

You could take a [optional chaining operator `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) with a default of an empty string.

```
const
    name = this.props.objects
        .find(({ id }) => id === this.state.selectedObject.id)
        ?.name || '';
```